# Does the dual action of $H^{-1/2}$ on $H^{1/2} \cap C^\infty$ depend on pointwise values?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Here is the inspiration for my question:  it is easy to see that the self-dual action of an element $f \in L^2(a,b)$ on $L^2(a,b) \cap C^\infty (a,b)$ does not depend on pointwise values.  Indeed, if $h \in L^2(a,b) \cap C^\infty (a,b)$, then for any point $c \in (a,b)$ we can write $h = (h - h(c) \phi_{(c-\frac{1}{n} , c+\frac{1}{n})} ) + h(c)\phi_{(c-\frac{1}{n} , c+\frac{1}{n})} $, where $\phi_{(c-\frac{1}{n} , c+\frac{1}{n})}$ is a bump function with $\phi_{(c-\frac{1}{n} , c+\frac{1}{n})}(c)=1$, and since $\int_a^b f \phi_{(c-\frac{1}{n} , c+\frac{1}{n})} \, dx \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, we have $\int_a^b f \left( h - h(c)\phi_{(c-\frac{1}{n} , c+\frac{1}{n})} \right) \, dx \to \int_a^b fh \, dx$ .

However, what if we consider instead $f \in H^{-1/2}(a,b)$ acting on $H^{1/2}(a,b) \cap C^\infty (a,b)$?  To attempt a parallel of the argument above, we would need an analog of the bump functions that would work in $H^{1/2}(a,b)$; that is, we would need a family of functions $\psi_n \in C^\infty(a,b)$ that satisfy $\psi_n(c)=1$, $\|\psi_n \|_{H^{1/2}} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

**My question:**  Does such a sequence exist?

**Some context as to why I'm interested:**  I am interested in extending weakly defined partial differential equations from half-spaces to whole spaces, and want to know when it is possible to break test functions up across the boundary.

Thanks for any help and insights!

Comment: If point evaluation were a continuous linear functional, we'd have a continuous embedding of $H^{1/2}(a,b)$ into $C(a,b)$.  But Sobolev embeddings say $H^k(a,b)$ should only embed in $C(a,b)$ for $k \ge 1$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks - I too have been thinking that Sobolev embedding in one form or another should have something to say about this.  However, I could be being dense, but I don't see that the existence of the sequence in question would imply that point evaluation were a continuous linear functional on $H^{1/2}$?

Comment: I would tend to think that the requirement of the question is conceivably weaker than the question of whether Dirac delta is in $H^{-1/2}$... But maybe I'm mistaken. I'll think more later.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks for your comment.  It seems to me that actually the sequence should exist precisely because the Dirac delta does not belong to $H^{-1/2}$ - maybe this is actually what Nate meant and I misinterpreted which side his argument was coming down on.  I still can't make the intuition precise by coming up with an example sequence, though...